# Can't manage to adjust Boxplot margins separately in r

Tags: r, statistics, boxplot

I've created a boxplot and set the x-labels to be perpendicular to the x-axis, which then forced me to adjust the margins so that the actual x-axis title doesn't overlap with the x-axis labels. However in doing so, the y-axis title has been moved equally as far, meaning theres a big gap between it and the y-axis. Is there a way that I could fix this to perhaps change them separately?

```
boxplot(spend~region, data=spendbyregion, main="Boxplot showing distribution 
of expense by location", 
        xlab="expense", ylab="location", las=2) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(family = "Trebuchet MS", color = "#111111", face ="bold", size=20, hjust=0.5))
  par(mar=c(14, 15, 4.1, 2.1), mgp=c(10.5,1,0))
```

[Boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3KqA.png)

Comment: Maybe you need to use `ggplot2`.

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data so that we can work with your code? The best way is using `dput(spendbyreligion)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code, not all of which I will address here. Your key problem seems to be the use of the `mgp` argument of the `par` function. **`mgp`**, is valid for **both axes**.

You may take play around with  `mai` (setting the margins in inches), and `cex.axis` (font size of the axis labels). Even then, if you treat both axes in the same way, you will have a problem.

The following does work: suppress the generation of the X-axis title and create it manually with `xtext()`

```
# First creating some mimicking data
regions <- c("East Midlands", "Eastern", "London", "Norht East", "North West Merseyside", 
             "Northern Ireland", "Scotland", "South East", "South West", "Wales", "West Midlands", 
             "Yorkshire and the Humber")
spendings <- rnorm(1200, mean = 350, sd = 6)
spendbyregion <- data.frame(spend = spendings, region = rep(regions, 100))

# increase the bottom margin   
# to be called before plotting 
par(mai = c(2.0, 0.8, 0.8, 0.4))

# create plot; suppress xlab; decrease font size of axis labels
boxplot(spend ~ region, data = spendbyregion, main = "Boxplot showing distribution 
        of expense by location", xlab = "", ylab = "expense", las = 2, cex.axis = .7) 

# manually create X axis label
mtext(text = "location", side = 1, line = 8)

# reset defaults
par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 2), 
    mgp = c(3, 1, 0),
    mai = c(1.0, 0.8, 0.8, 0.4))
```

Please let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: @Wary My pleasure. If you are happy, could you please mark the answer as "useful" and/or as "chosen solution". Thank you !